# Buena resolución de imagen causa "OutOfMemoryError"

Tags: android, android-imageview, out-of-memory-error

tengo una duda como puedo trabajar con imágenes de buena resolución, ya que al ponerlas se me pone lenta la aplicación, quisiera saber si hay una forma de trabajar con una resolución aceptable sin que afecta a la velocidad de la aplicación.
Por ejemplo una galería de imágenes que a medida que desplazo se me pone lenta la aplicación.
Gracias de antemano.

```
public class AdapterAlbum extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterAlbum.ViewHolderClase> {



public class ViewHolderClase extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ImageView imageView;

    public ViewHolderClase(View itemView) {

        super(itemView);
        imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cover);
    }
}

@Override
public ViewHolderClase onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View viewItem = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.album, null);
    return new ViewHolderClase(viewItem);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolderClase holder, int position) {
    holder.imageView.setBackgroundResource(Activity.imagenes.get(position));


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return Activity.imagenes.size();
}
```

}
bueno en si el diseño donde cargo las imágenes es sencillo, cave resaltar que mis imagenes son aproximadamente de 43.4k por tener un poco mas de resolución

Actividad:

```
    public class Actividad {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    static ArrayList<Integer> imagenes;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        imagenes = new ArrayList<>();
        imagenes.addAll(Arrays.asList(R.drawable.cold22, R.drawable.cover3, R.drawable.coverr,
                R.drawable.cover6, R.drawable.cold3, R.drawable.cover4, R.drawable.cover87, R.drawable.cover12));
        contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activ, null);
        return contentView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreated(savedInstanceState);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) contentView.findViewById(R.id.reyclerViewTres);
        layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        adapter = new AdapterAlbum();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

}
```

Comment: Hola @NO54D tus imagenes se estan cargando en un ViewPager, podrias poner un poco de codigo?

Comment: Gunnar esto te ayudara a optimizar tu código! 1) Elimina la creación de la lista de imagenes en la Actividad:  imagenes = new ArrayList<>();
        imagenes.addAll(Arrays.asList(R.drawable.cold22, R.drawable.cover3, R.drawable.coverr,
                R.drawable.cover6, R.drawable.cold3, R.drawable.cover4, R.drawable.cover87, R.drawable.cover12));

Comment: 2) En la clase adapter agregar este arreglo de ints : private static final int[] MIS_IMAGENES = new int[]{R.drawable.cold22, R.drawable.cover3, R.drawable.coverr,
   R.drawable.cover6, R.drawable.cold3, R.drawable.cover4, R.drawable.cover87, R.drawable.cover12};

Comment: 3) En el método getItemCount() del adapter cambia a:
  return (MIS_IMAGENES.length;

Comment: 4) agrega las imagenes en el adapter  de esta forma: 
 holder.imageView.setBackgroundResource(MIS_IMAGENES[position]);

Comment: Gracias @Elenasys lo cambie realmente funciona esta mucho mejor , una pregunta uso ViewPaer  y de momento para pasar a la sección de galería no lo hace con fluidez, perdón por la molestia y Gracias .

Comment: Que bien, me alegra!, evita usar relaciones con la actividad principal como en : holder.imageView.setBackgroundResource(Activity.imagenes.get(position)); .  Si deseas realiza otra pregunta con lo del ViewPager para no llenar de comentarios aquí, no puedo entrar a Chat porque estoy blocked!  :(

Comment: Esta muy bien @Elenasys gracias

Comment: Te recomiendo usar Glide. A mi me ha traido excelentes resultados. Saludos

Comment: Mi solución!! https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/206632/buena-resoluci%C3%B3n-de-imagen-ralentiza-la-app-cargar-imagen-desde-uri-soluciona

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### ¿Como evitar Out of memory en aplicación Android?

Esto es una buena pregunta, cual es la medida que deberían tener las imágenes en una aplicación para que la misma no consuma mucha memoria y por lo tanto sea lenta?.

En realidad la respuesta es que deben ser de una resolución aceptable pero un peso en kbs pequeño (algo similar a imágenes usadas en paginas web), esto para evitar principalmente dentro de la aplicación procesamiento y manipulación en memoria de la imagen y consumo de ancho de banda que pudiera ser innecesario.

Como lograr que tu imagen sea ligera?, bueno puedes trabajar con la **[compresión](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compresi%C3%B3n_de_imagen)** en bytes.

Aquí un tutorial: https://sites.google.com/site/ticvalcarcel/optimizacion-de-imagenes-para-internet/tamano-y-peso-de-las-imagenes

---

> **Tamaño y peso de las imágenes** Muchos de nosotros hemos comprobado, y sufrido, cómo una página web con bastantes imágenes se ralentizaba
> o, como un mensaje de correo electrónico con un powerpoint de fotos
> adjunto, parecía que no se iba a descargar nunca.
>
> Un concepto y expresión que usamos al hablar de imágenes es el de
> tamaño. Este término puede ocasionar confusión ya que solemos
> emplearlo para cosas diferentes: normalmente decimos que una imagen
> tiene un tamaño de 13 x 18 cm o 1024 x 768 píxeles, pero también
> decimos que una imagen tiene un tamaño de 3 Mbytes. Este uso impreciso
> de la palabra no suele causar mayores problemas, pero para los
> objetivos del curso sí que es importante matizar, ya que son dos
> características diferentes de una imagen.
>
> De esta forma, en este tema, cuando hablemos del tamaño nos
> referiremos sólo a las dimensiones de la imagen: 13 x 18 cm, 1024 x
> 768 píxeles; y cuando se hable del espacio que ocupa la imagen en el
> dispositivo de almacenamiento –disco, memoria…- (3 Mbytes o 149
> Kbytes) lo definiremos como peso.
>
> De esta manera, podemos decir que una imagen es:
>
> Grande cuando tiene un tamaño igual o mayor a 1024x768 píxeles Mediana
> cuando el tamaño va de 320x240 a 1024x768 píxeles Pequeña cuando el
> tamaño es menor a 320x240 píxeles Muy pequeña cuando es menor a
> 100x100 píxeles O que es:
>
> Pesada si tiene 1 MB o más De peso mediano si va de 300KB a 1 MB
> Ligera si su peso es menor de 300KB Muy ligera si el peso es inferior
> a 100KB Al reducir de peso las imágenes (de mapa de bits) hacemos que
> tengan menos bytes y, por tanto, que:
>
> Ocupen menos espacio en un dispositivo de almacenamiento. Por ejemplo,
> el disco duro de un servidor de Internet acojerá más imágenes en un
> mismo espacio. La transferencia de datos por una red sea más veloz,
> acelerando así la descarga de imágenes y la navegación por internet.

> **Aligerar ≠ Optimizar**
>
> Puede darse que el caso que al “aligerar” de peso una foto, la
> reduzcamos también de calidad. Al optimizar, lo que pretendemos es
> reducir el peso lo máximo posible, pero sin que la imagen sufra
> pérdida de calidad aparente.

---

El SDK de Android tiene una forma de optimizar el cargado de imágenes, que implica el tomar un formato de imagen mas pequeno por medio de la clase **[BitmapFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeByteArray(byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options))**:

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Otras recomendadas considerando una previa optimización de las imágenes son el uso de dos librerías principalmente,

[**GLIDE**](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) y **[PICASSO](http://square.github.io/picasso/)**, cuya implementación es sencilla y muy similar.

Existen otras opciones pero realizando un benchmark a mi parecer son las mejores opciones.

En cuanto a tu problema :

> galería de imágenes que a medida que desplazo se me pone lenta la
> aplicación.

Debes asegurar que la imagen sea desalojada del `ImageView` para que el `Garbage Collector` la pueda eliminar de memoria, esto en cuando ya no sea visible en la pantalla, porque si se están acumulando podrías tener después de cierto tiempo un  `Java.Lang.OutOfMemoryError`, lo puedes realizar con:

```
miImageView.setBackgroundDrawable(null)
```

o

```
miImageView.setImageDrawable(null);
```

Comment: Hola @Elenasys  bueno en si en en un recyclerView pero aun asi se me pone lento la app

Comment: @NO54D primero tienes que optimizar tus imagenes, si cargas imagenes de 2 MB por ejemplo el reciclaje ayuda pero aún es considerable el tamaño, puedo ver un ejemplo de tus imagenes? o tu proyecto?

Comment: Esta bien @Elenasys por que no ahora subo el codigo

Comment: Ya lo subí @Elenasys

Comment: Listo, revisa mis comentarios en tu pregunta! :)

Answer (score 5):

Te aconsejo utilizar alguno de los 3 famosos frameworks para estas tareas, y recuerda que muchas de estas tareas requieren ciertos permisos. Mi recomendación es Glide para imágenes y Volley para todo lo demás.

> **Picasso**, ideal para imágenes de grandes resoluciones: [Enlace](http://square.github.io/picasso)

```
Picasso.with(context).load(address).into(imageView);
```

> **Glide**, ideal para imágenes de resoluciones aceptadas: [Enlace](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

```
Glide.with(context).load(address).into(imageView);
```

> **Volley**, ideal para transmisión de datos GET/POST, acepta JSON: [Enlace](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley)

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(Volley.newRequestQueue(context), new BitmapLruCache());

<com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgAvatar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

NetworkImageView imgAvatar = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgAvatar);
imageView.setImageUrl(url, imageLoader);
```

Answer (score 1):

Carga la imagen cuando vaya a usarse y elimínala cuando no, si vas cargando imágenes pero no las eliminas, tu aplicación cada vez consumirá mas memoria.
Por otra parte, te aconsejo que uses imágenes con una resolución acorde a la aplicación, y si no es factible redimensionala.

Answer (score 1):

Yo uso la librería `Glide` para cargar imágenes en un `viewImage`, el mismo se encarga de rendimensionarlas apropiadamente para el dispositivo y las guardar en la cache para agilizar el proceso posteriormente.
Prueba a ver si aún te sigue dando problema de rendimiento.