# ¿Por qué mi aplicación va lenta al cambiar de una actividad a otra?

Tags: android

[image: Este es el código de la actividad principal al pulsar en el botón siguiente debo pasar al siguiente color, pero se demora alrededor de 3 segundos para presentar la siguiente actividad]

```
public class ColorRojo extends Activity{
    private ImageView imagen1,imagen2;
    private  MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_rojo);
        imagen1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myimage1);
        imagen1.setOnTouchListener(touch);
        imagen2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myimage2);
        findViewById(R.id.myimage1).setOnDragListener(arrastrar);
        findViewById(R.id.myimage2).setOnDragListener(arrastrar);

    }

    View.OnTouchListener touch=new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(v);
                v.startDrag(null, shadowBuilder, v, 0);
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    };


    View.OnDragListener arrastrar=new View.OnDragListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction()==DragEvent.ACTION_DROP) {
                View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
                if(view.getId()==R.id.myimage1 && v.getId()==R.id.myimage2)
                {
                    imagen1.setX(0);
                    imagen2.setY(0);
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Asociacion correcta",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                   iniciar(view);
                    return true;
                }  else {
                    return false;
                }

            }
           return true;
        }
};

public void destruir() {
    if (mMediaPlayer != null)
        mMediaPlayer.release();
}

public void iniciar(View v) {
    destruir();
    mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.maru2);
    mMediaPlayer.start();
}
```

El problema de mi aplicación reside en que al pulsar el botón siguiente y mostrar otro color se demora en abrir la siguiente actividad alrededor de 3 segundos.

Comment: Hola soy programador novato, el problema de mi aplicacion reside en que al pulsar el boton siguiente y mostrar otro color se demora en abrir la siguiente actividad alrededor de 3 segundos.

Comment: Buenas. Te recomiendo editar tu pregunta, poner el contenido de tu comentario al inicio de la misma y borrar el comentario. Eso mejorará la legibilidad del tema. Un saludo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existen varios puntos a optimizar, primeramente es importante hacer nulas instancias que no se necesitan al destruir la actividad para que no se queden en memoria.

Se recomienda realizarlo dentro del método `onDestroy()` y esta sería la forma correcta de hacerlo con el `MediaPlayer`:

```
@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
   if (mMediaPlayer != null){
             mMediaPlayer.stop();
             mMediaPlayer.release();
             mMediaPlayer  = null;
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

Revisando tu código me parece que ese es el problema.

Noto que usas imágenes que cargas en `ImageView`´s, así que podrías eliminar las imágenes en el mismo método `onDestroy()` para que el Garbage Collector las elimine!

```
imageView.setImageDrawable(null);
```

Revisa esta pregunta, te podría ayudar a optimizar tu aplicación:

[ViewPager, buena Resolución de una imagen](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6343/buena-resoluci%C3%B3n-de-una-imagen)

Comment: Gracias me ayudo tu propuesta de solución un saludo @Elenasys

Comment: Excellent, me alegra mucho te ayudo, saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias Angel,  @AngelAngel ya corregí, estoy en ocasiones desde un móvil y es un poco complicado

Comment: jaja tienes razón un poco de cafeina!, debe ser != ya que si es nulo no se puede realizar .stop() ni .release() provocaría un NullPointerException!  :)