# Error ImageView Android

Tags: android

tengo el siguiente error al agregar un ImageView. este es mi imageview y el error

```
   android:layout_width="130dp"
   android:layout_height="130dp"
   android:src="@drawable/mi_imagen_icon"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
   android:id="@+id/imageView"
   android:layout_marginTop="-11dp"
```

el error

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.example.nicolas.miproyecto, PID: 8618
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 51301388 byte allocation with 4635664 free bytes and 4MB until OOM
     at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1080)
     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2635)
     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2540)
     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:870)
     at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:152)
     at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:140)
     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:57)
     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:53)
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:972)
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1031)
     at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:746)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276)
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
     at com.example.nicolas.jobworks.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Ve mi respuesta y te sugiero agregar tu código para que los desarrolladores te den sugerencias de optimización

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que la imagen utilizada es demasiado grande al manipularla consume demasiada memoria.

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 51301388 byte
>   allocation with 4635664 free bytes and 4MB until OOM

Trata con una versión más optimizada en peso y tamaño de tu imagen.

Revisa esta respuesta :
[ViewPager, buena Resolución de una imagen](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6343/buena-resoluci%C3%B3n-de-una-imagen)
para tener algunos de tips de como solucionar tu problema.

Comment: gracias elena solucionado.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes un error de memoria al cargar la imagen, lo que deberías de hacer es hacerle un resize antes de mostrarla y después cargarla programaticamente al ImageView

```
public Bitmap resizeBitmap(int targetW, int targetH) {
BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath, bmOptions);
int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

int scaleFactor = 1;
if ((targetW > 0) || (targetH > 0)) {
        scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW/targetW, photoH/targetH);        
}

bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath, bmOptions);
}
```

Y asignas el bitmap al ImageView con `tuImageView.setImageBitmap().`