# Problemas al correr aplicación de Animacion Android Studio

Tags: android

Estoy trabajando en una pequeña animacion con android y tengo un problema a la hora de correrlo.

Estos son los archivos con los que trabajo:

[image: Archivos]

Mi animación:

animation-list... android:oneshot="false"

```
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/android01"
    android:duration="5" />
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/android02"
    android:duration="5" />
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/android03"
    android:duration="5" />
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/android04"
    android:duration="5" />
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/android05"
    android:duration="5" />
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/android06"
    android:duration="5" />
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/android07"
    android:duration="5" />
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/android08"
    android:duration="5" />
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/android09"
    android:duration="5" />
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/android10"
    android:duration="5" />
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/android11"
    android:duration="5" />
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/android12"
    android:duration="5" />
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/android13"
    android:duration="5" />
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/android14"
    android:duration="5" />
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/android15"
    android:duration="5" />
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/android16"
    android:duration="5" />
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/android17"
    android:duration="5" />
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/android18"
    android:duration="5" />
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/android19"
    android:duration="5" />
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/android20"
    android:duration="5" />
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/android21"
    android:duration="5" />
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/android22"
    android:duration="5" />
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/android23"
    android:duration="5" />
```

... Este vendría a ser el código del activity:

AnimationDrawable anim;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImageView and=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    and.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.framebyframe);

    anim=(AnimationDrawable) and.getBackground();
    anim.start();

}
```

Y este el error:

[image: Error android]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raphael, el error que se muestra en el LogCat es :

> **Java.Lang.OutOfMemoryError**

Debes tomar en cuenta que las imágenes deben estar optimizadas, no es necesario cargar imágenes de un tamaño considerable ya que el sistema operativo podría tener problemas al manipularlas en memoria y puede consumir considerablemente la memoria, después de todo van a mostrarse en un dispositivo móvil.

trata con versiones más pequeñas de tus imágenes.

Revisa los tips de optimización para las imágenes en esta respuesta:

https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/6359/95

https://sites.google.com/site/ticvalcarcel/optimizacion-de-imagenes-para-internet/tamano-y-peso-de-las-imagenes