# Como liberar Memoria en mi aplicacion android

Tags: android, manejo-de-memoria

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Buenos dias

Ya estoy en proceso de pruebas de mi aplicacion android, y tengo una pregunta lo que pasa es que al estar haciendo varios movimientos, se congela la app y se pone un poco lenta, lo que veo es por detalle de memoria de mi app, no la esta liberando, alguien me podria decir como se libera la memoria en una app android.

Gracias.

Como les decia en si el problema lo tengo en mi ultima pantalla que es donde el usuario tiene que generar cobros.. ahorita ya puse un metodo para que me este borrando el cache de mi aplicacion... les dejo el codigo del activity donde tengo el problema y la pantalla...

Activity detalle

public class Detalle_Cliente extends AppCompatActivity {

//Controles
    public Button pagar;
    public Button Pagoc;

```
//Dialogos
ProgressDialog dialog;
AlertDialog alert = null;

//Array Detalle
ListView list;
ArrayList<DetalleCxP> DetalleArrayList = new ArrayList<DetalleCxP>();
MyArrayAdapter adaptador;

CXCPSaldoClienteProveedor O_Cliente;
DetalleMenu O_DetalleMenu;
Integer I_FormaPago=0;


//Manejo de Intent
public Bundle extras;
public Intent intent;
public String UsuarioCap;

//Ubicacion GPS
LocationManager locManager;
LocationListener locListener;


final Context context = this;
public String obser;
private static final String TAG = "mx.com.oncontrol.oncontrolmovile";

//Forma de Pago
public TextView formap;

//Array Forma de Pago
ArrayList<FormaPago> PagoArrayList = new ArrayList<FormaPago>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detalle__cliente);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //Manejo de Intent
    extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    UsuarioCap = extras.getString("UsuarioCaptura2");
    intent = getIntent();
    O_DetalleMenu=(DetalleMenu) intent.getSerializableExtra("O_DetalleMenu");
    intent=getIntent();
    O_Cliente=(CXCPSaldoClienteProveedor) intent.getSerializableExtra("O_Cliente");
    setTitle(O_Cliente.getClienteDescripcion());

    //codigo listview
    list=(ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.listDeta);
    AsyncCallWSDetalle task = new AsyncCallWSDetalle();
    //Call execute
    task.execute();
    comenzarLocalizacion();

   pagar = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btnpago);
    pagar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Detalle_Cliente.this);
            alert.setMessage("¿Estas Seguro de Aplicar el Abono?");
            alert.setTitle("Confirmacion");

            alert.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()  {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    I_FormaPago=((FormaPago)((Spinner)findViewById(R.id.menu_spinner1)).getSelectedItem()).getId();

                    comenzarLocalizacion();
                    AsyncGrabarCXCP task = new AsyncGrabarCXCP();


                    //Call execute
                    task.execute();
                }
            });
            alert.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            alert.show();
        }
    });


    Pagoc = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btn_pagoceros);
    Pagoc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            View pron = li.inflate(R.layout.row_dialog, null);

            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            alert.setTitle("Confirmacion de Pago en 0!");
            alert.setMessage("Favor Ingresa el Motivo Por el " +
                              "cual no se realizo el Pago");
            alert.setView(pron);
            final EditText observ = (EditText)pron.findViewById(R.id.edtobser);
            obser = observ.getText().toString();
            alert.setCancelable(false);
            alert.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                comenzarLocalizacion();
                AsyncGrabarCXCP task = new AsyncGrabarCXCP();
                obser = observ.getText().toString();
                //Call execute
                task.execute();
            }
        });
            alert.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                       dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            alert.show();
        }
    });

}
//Codigo de Buscador en la parte del ActionBar
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_detalle, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_spinner1);
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);

    //Se manda a llamar el metodo del spinner
    AsyncForma task = new AsyncForma();
    //Call execute
    task.execute();
    return true;

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}



private void comenzarLocalizacion() {
    //Obtenemos una referencia al LocationManager
    locManager =
            (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    //Obtenemos la última posición conocida
    Location loc = locManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    if(loc != null)
    {
        O_Cliente.setGPSLocation("http://maps.google.com/maps?q=" + String.valueOf(loc.getLatitude() + ",+" + String.valueOf(loc.getLongitude())));
    }


    //Nos registramos para recibir actualizaciones de la posición
    locListener = new LocationListener() {


        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            if(location.getLatitude() != 0.0D && location.getLongitude() != 0.0D) {
                try {
                    Geocoder e = new Geocoder(Detalle_Cliente.this, Locale.getDefault());
                    List list = e.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
                    if(!list.isEmpty()) {
                        Address DirCalle = (Address)list.get(0);
                        //direccion.setText("Mi direccion es: \n" + DirCalle.getAddressLine(0));
                        O_Cliente.setGPSLocation2(DirCalle.getAddressLine(0));
                    }
                } catch (IOException var5) {
                    var5.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            //lblEstado.setText("Provider OFF");
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            //lblEstado.setText("Provider ON ");
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            /*Log.i("", "Provider Status: " + status);
            lblEstado.setText("Provider Status: " + status);*/
        }
    };

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    locManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, locListener);
}


private class AsyncCallWSDetalle extends AsyncTask<String, ArrayList, ArrayList> {


    @Override
    protected ArrayList doInBackground(String... params){
        DetalleArrayList=webService.DetalleCxP(O_Cliente.getCliente(), O_DetalleMenu.getDocumento());
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    //Make Progress Bar visible
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        dialog=new ProgressDialog(Detalle_Cliente.this);
        dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        dialog.setMessage("Cargando Detalle...");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();

    }

    //Once WebService returns response
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList arrayList) {
        super.onPostExecute(arrayList);
        if(DetalleArrayList.size()!=0){
            dialog.dismiss();

            adaptador= new MyArrayAdapter(Detalle_Cliente.this, DetalleArrayList);///* no se usa your_array_list

            list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listDeta);
            list.setAdapter(adaptador);
            adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();


        }else{
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}




public class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DetalleCxP> {


    public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<DetalleCxP> ArrayClientes) {
        super(context, 0, ArrayClientes);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        DetalleCxP O_DetalleCxP = getItem(position);

        // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_detalle, parent, false);
            //Abono = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono);
            //attach the TextWatcher listener to the EditText
            ((EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono)).addTextChangedListener(new TB_Abono_Watcher(convertView));
        }

        //Obteniendo instancias de los text views
        /*
        vencido = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtvencido);
        saldo = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txttotal);
        Abono = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono);
        total = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.total);
```

*/

```
        DecimalFormat numberFormat  = new DecimalFormat("###,##0.00");

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");



        ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtFecha)).setText(dateFormat.format(O_DetalleCxP.getFecha()));


        ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtFolio)).setText(O_DetalleCxP.getFolio());

        ((EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono)).setTag(O_DetalleCxP);
        if (O_DetalleCxP.TotalAplicado>0)
        {
            ((EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono)).setText(numberFormat.format(O_DetalleCxP.TotalAplicado));
        }
        else
        {
            ((EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono)).setText("");
        }

        ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.total)).setText(numberFormat.format(O_DetalleCxP.getTotal()));
        ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txttotal)).setText(numberFormat.format(O_DetalleCxP.getSaldo()));
        ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtvencido)).setText(numberFormat.format(O_DetalleCxP.getSaldoVencido()));




        //Devolver al ListView la fila creada
        return convertView;

    }
}



//Clase para Edittext
private class TB_Abono_Watcher implements TextWatcher{


   Button pagar =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnpago);
    private View view;
    private TB_Abono_Watcher(View view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        //do nothing
    }
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
    {

        //Abono = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono);
        DetalleCxP O_DetalleCxP = (DetalleCxP)((EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono)).getTag();
        O_DetalleCxP.TotalAplicado=ONC_SYS.NullToZeroDouble(s.toString());

        Double Total=0.0;
        for(int i=0;i<DetalleArrayList.size();i++)
        {
            if (((DetalleCxP)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).TotalAplicado>0)
            {
                Total += ((DetalleCxP)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).TotalAplicado;
            }
        }
        DecimalFormat numberFormat  = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtTotal)).setText(numberFormat.format(Total));

        if (Total==0)
        {
            ((Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_pagoceros)).setEnabled(true);
            ((Button)findViewById(R.id.btnpago)).setEnabled(false);
        }
        else
        {
            ((Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_pagoceros)).setEnabled(false);
            ((Button)findViewById(R.id.btnpago)).setEnabled(true);
        }


        //Validacion que no te deje hacer un abono Mayo al saldo vencido
        if (O_DetalleCxP.getSaldo() < O_DetalleCxP.TotalAplicado)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No puedes Aplicar un Abono Mayor al SaldoVencido",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ((EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono)).setText("");

        }
    }
}


//Medoto para Grabar datos

public class AsyncGrabarCXCP extends AsyncTask<Void,Integer,String>
{
    int Recurso;


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog=new ProgressDialog(Detalle_Cliente.this);
        dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        dialog.setMessage("Procesando Datos...");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String Resultado="";

        Recurso=webService.ObtenerRecurso();
        String Folio = webService.ObtenerFolio(35);
        Date O_D = new Date();

        Double Factor=0.0, Importe=0.0, Descuento=0.0, SubTotal=0.0, Total=0.0, IVA=0.0,Retencion1=0.0,Retencion2=0.0,IEPS=0.0;

        Double DFactor=0.0;

        final int count = DetalleArrayList.size();

        for(int i=0;i<count;i++) {

            Factor=0.0;

            if (((DetalleCxP)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).TotalAplicado>0)
            {
                Factor = ((DetalleCxP)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).TotalAplicado / ((DetalleCxP)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).Total;

                Importe += ((DetalleCxP)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).Importe*Factor;
                Descuento += ((DetalleCxP)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).Descuento*Factor;
                SubTotal += ((DetalleCxP)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).SubTotal*Factor;
                IVA += ((DetalleCxP)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).IVA*Factor;
                Retencion1 += ((DetalleCxP)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).Retencion1*Factor;
                Retencion2 += ((DetalleCxP)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).Retencion2*Factor;
                IEPS += ((DetalleCxP)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).IEPS*Factor;
                Total += ((DetalleCxP)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).Total*Factor;
            }

        }


        Resultado = webService.LLenarEncabezadoCXCP(Recurso,
                "I",    //Accion I
                0,      //Id = 0
                O_Cliente.getEmpresa(), //Id de Empresa
                Folio,
                new Date(),
                O_Cliente.getCliente(),
                O_Cliente.getProveedor(),
                O_Cliente.getMoneda(),
                1.0,      //Tipo de Cambio por default 1
                0,      //Cuenta Bancaria
                UsuarioCap, //Usuario Captura
                I_FormaPago,          //Pago Forma
                Total,          //Saldo
                Importe,    //Importe
                0,          //Financiamiento
                Descuento,
                SubTotal,
                Retencion1,
                Retencion2,
                IEPS,
                IVA,
                0,          //ISH,
                Total,      //Total
                Total,      //totalaplicado,
                "A",        //status,
                "",         //usucariocancela,
                0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,   //Numero1...Numero10
                O_Cliente.getGPSLocation(), //Texto1
                O_Cliente.getGPSLocation2(),  //Texto2
                "","","","","","","","",                      //Texto1...Texto10
                new Date(),new Date(),new Date(),new Date(),new Date(),new Date(),  //Fecha1...Texto6
                obser,         //Observacion
                0,0,0,0,0,0,         //Catalogo1...Catalogo6
                "",         //ordencompra
                0,          //concepto
                "",         //observacioncancelacion
                0,          //origenventacompra,
                0           //origeninventario
        );
        if (Resultado.equals("OK"))
        {

            for(int i=0;i<DetalleArrayList.size();i++) {



                if (((DetalleCxP)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).TotalAplicado>0)
                {
                    DFactor = ((DetalleCxP)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).TotalAplicado / ((DetalleCxP)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).Total;


                    Resultado = webService.LLenarDetalleCXCP(Recurso,
                            "I", //Accion
                            0, //id
                            ((DetalleCxP)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).getId(),  //Origen
                            ((DetalleCxP)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).getDocumento(),  //OrigenDocumento
                            (Double)(((DetalleCxP)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).Importe*DFactor),   //Importe
                            (Double)0.0,  //Financiamiento
                            (Double)(((DetalleCxP)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).Descuento*DFactor), //Descuento
                            (Double)(((DetalleCxP)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).SubTotal*DFactor),   //Subtotal
                            (Double)(((DetalleCxP)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).Retencion1*DFactor), //Retencion1
                            (Double)(((DetalleCxP)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).Retencion2*DFactor),  //Retencion2
                            (Double)(((DetalleCxP)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).IEPS*DFactor),   //IEPS
                            (Double)(((DetalleCxP)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).IVA*DFactor), //IVA
                            (Double)0.0, //ISH
                            (Double)(((DetalleCxP)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).Total*DFactor),  //Total
                            ((DetalleCxP)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).getSaldo(),   //Saldo
                            "Android App"      //Referencia
                    );

                }

            }

        }


        if (Resultado.equals("OK"))

        {

            Resultado = webService.GrabarCxCP(Recurso,//Recurso
                    O_DetalleMenu.getModulo(),      //Modulo
                    O_DetalleMenu.getOperacion(),      //Operacion
                    O_DetalleMenu.getDocumento(),      //Documento
                    0,      //OrigenId
                    0);     //OrigenDocumento
        }

        return Resultado;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String Resultado) {
        super.onPostExecute(Resultado);
        if (Resultado.equals("LA OPERACION FUE REALIZADA CON EXITO"))
        {
            dialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Datos Guardado Correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
            }else{
                dialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error en el Webservices" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
    }
}

public DetalleCxP FindCXCPSaldoClienteProveedorById(int Id)
{
    for(int i=0;i<DetalleArrayList.size();i++)
    {
        if (DetalleArrayList.get(i).getId()==Id)
        {
            return DetalleArrayList.get(i);
        }
    }
    return null;
}


private class AsyncForma extends AsyncTask<String, ArrayList, ArrayList>
{

    @Override
    protected ArrayList doInBackground(String... params) {
        PagoArrayList=webService.FormaPago();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList arrayList) {
        super.onPostExecute(arrayList);

        if(PagoArrayList.size()!=0){

            Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.menu_spinner1);
            ArrayAdapter<FormaPago> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<FormaPago>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, PagoArrayList);
            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        }else{

        }
    }
}



@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
@SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i(TAG, "onDestroy");
   DetalleArrayList = null;
    list = null;
    adaptador = null;
    O_DetalleMenu = null;
    extras = null;
    intent = null;
    UsuarioCap = null;
    obser = null;
    PagoArrayList = null;
    deleteCache(context);
    System.gc();
}


public static void deleteCache(Context context) {
    try {
        File dir = context.getCacheDir();
        deleteDir(dir);
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}

public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
    if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
        String[] children = dir.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
            if (!success) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return dir.delete();
    }
    else if(dir!= null && dir.isFile())
        return dir.delete();
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Hugo, recominendo agregues tu código ya que al ser un poco lenta tu application pueden ser diversas causas que expongo en mi respuesta.

Comment: Un articulo interesante en usar weakreferences https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/finally-understanding-how-references-work-in-android-and-java-26a0d9c92f83

Answer (score 2):

> se congela la app

Evitar realizar procesos que bloqueen la UI, si el hilo principal es bloqueado podras notar que tu aplicación se "congela" por unos instantes.

En este caso puedes usar [**runOnUIThread**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)) o [**Asynctask**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

> se pone un poco lenta, lo que veo es por detalle de memoria de mi
>   app, no la esta liberando

Existen varias causas de esto, podrían ser objetos que no están siendo eliminados de memoria por el Garbage collector como listeners o vistas etc. Regularmente el problema principal son las imágenes o son muy grandes y al ser manipuladas por la aplicación consumen una gran cantidad de memoria, o no se estan eliminando de los contenedores,  se debe asegurar también quitar la referencia de las imágenes dentro de los `imageView` cuando no los utilicemos:

```
miImageView.setBackgroundDrawable(null)
```

Te recomiendo revises esta respuesta:
https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/6359/95

Comment: seria lo mismo con mis edittext, textview?

Comment: Si los estas agregando programaticamente a un contenedor si!

Comment: yo lo estoy agregando desde el panel de controles, entonces no es necesario?

Comment: No es necesario ya que en realidad están insertados en el layout.

Answer (score 0):

Usa el monitor de recursos donde aparece las gráficas `Memory, CPU, Network` así podrás ver realmente donde ocurre las cargas, y vas descartando partes.

Busca también información sobre posibles `Memory leacks` enlace: [Memory leak from bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23857091/memory-leak-from-bitmap)

Comment: tambien tiene que ver que hardware tiene mi dispositivo movil? por que en mi emulador no me hace lo que en mi dispositovo si

Comment: @HugoRodriguez puede, que el emulador tiene disponibilidad de toda la memoria de tu maquina, prueba la app en diferentes dispositivos. Te recomiendo desarrollar siempre con el producto final y no tirar de emuladores.

Answer (score 0):

Normalmente el bajo rendimiento de nuestra aplicación se debe a que todo está corriendo sobre un único hilo, el principal. Te recomiendo que trates de trabajar con Hilos(Threads) para realizar las funciones por separado.

Te puedes apoyar del monitor de recursos y definir como seccionar la carga de la actividad.

Puedes apoyarte con el siguiente tutorial: [Hilos y Procesos (Developers)](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html)

Además siempre prueba con el dispositivo final, olvídate de los emuladores, sólo como consejo.

¡Mucha Suerte! :D

Comment: si de hecho si manejo hilos secundario usando Asynctask, solo que hay una pantalla donde se congela....

Comment: ya les agregue mi codigo y las pantallas