# Crear galeria de fotos android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Me gustaría poder desarrollar una actividad que accede a una carpeta con fotos y crea una galería para poder visualizarlas. Creo que tengo prácticamente todo hecho, pero por lo que sea no termina de visualizarse bien.

**Layout**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.oftecnica2.agendajose.GaleriaFotos"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Gallery
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/galeria" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagengaleria"
        android:layout_width="133dp"
        android:layout_height="194dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="#cfcfcf"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**clase java**:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Gallery;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.io.File;

public class GaleriaFotos extends AppCompatActivity {

    File[]fotos=null;
    String id="";
    Gallery galeria;
    ImageView imagengaleria;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_galeria_fotos);
        id=getIntent().getExtras().getString("id");
        imagengaleria=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagengaleria);

        cargoLista();

        galeria.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
        galeria.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                ImageView imagengaleria=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagengaleria);
                Bitmap foto = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fotos[i].getAbsolutePath());
                imagengaleria.setImageBitmap(foto);

            }
        });
    }

    public void cargoLista(){
        try{
            File fichero=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+"Reuniones"+File.separator+String.valueOf(id)+File.separator+"fotos");
            fotos=fichero.listFiles();
            galeria=(Gallery)findViewById(R.id.galeria);
            System.out.println("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
            for (File f:fotos){
                System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO");
        }
    }

    private class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context context;
        private int itemBackground;
        public ImageAdapter(Context c)
        {
            context = c;
            // sets a grey background; wraps around the images
            TypedArray a =obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.MyGallery);
            itemBackground = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.MyGallery_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
            a.recycle();
        }
        // returns the number of images
        public int getCount() {
            return fotos.length;
        }
        // returns the ID of an item
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }
        // returns the ID of an item
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }
        // returns an ImageView view
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fotos[position].getAbsolutePath());
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(100, 100));
            imageView.setBackgroundResource(itemBackground);
            return imageView;
        }
    }
}
```

Como veis, le paso por parámetro un número que es la carpeta donde están las fotos.

Al ejecutarlo a veces da el típico error de `outofmemory` y otras no aparece absolutamente nada. ¿Alguien ve los errores?

Comment: Sergio, usa Picasso o Glide y evitarias tener el problema, también considera no cargar imágenes demasiado grandes.

Comment: Obtienes el error outofmemory porque no eliminas los ítems que no se están visualizando y los mantienes a memoria, hasta que se llena.

Answer (score 2):

El tema de la galerías creadas a partir de un widget `Gallery` siempre ha sido un problema, los problemas son básicamente relacionados a que las imágenes al cargarse dentro de la ejecución de `getView()`, son cargadas dentro del `ImageView` pero cuando el `ImageView` no esta visible estas no son liberadas del mismo, en realidad estas cargando las imágenes y manteniendolas aún sin ser visualizadas.

Una solución rápida es eliminar la imagen del ImageView cuando esta no es visualizada mediante [setBackgroundDrawable()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)) asignandole un valor null:

```
miImageView.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
```

Pero existen otras consideraciones importantes como es el peso de la imagen, en dispositivos pequeños en ocasiones no es necesario el cargado de una imagen de tamaño grande ya que su manipulación en memoria es difícil y más aún si tenemos varias instancias provocaremos  `OutofMemory`.

Te sugiero revisar estos tips de optimización:
**[Buena resolución imagen](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/6359/95)**

y en el caso de tu galería recomiendo uses **[Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)** o **[Glide](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en)** dentro de

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
 ...
 ...
```

para cargar las imágenes dentro del `ImageView`, no soy de recomendar librerías pero en este caso son 2 buenas opciones que recomiendo, en realidad optimizan la imagen que cargan dentro de los `ImageView`, esto resulta en un bajo consumo de memoria el cual evitara problemas relacionados a `OutofMemory`.

Comment: no hay manera de conseguirlo...voy a probar con un as cardview en un recycler view...pueden cerrar la pregunta, gracias por sus respuestas :(

Comment: Usando picasso creo que puede realizar el trabajo, ya lo implementaste?

Comment: Agrega tu mensaje de LogCat porque pudiera ser otra la causa.

Comment: He probado con Picasso y la galeria seguia sin verse...La opcion a traves de la cual la he conseguido es usar recuclerview con picasso redimensionandolas, asi va muy fluido.

Comment: La opción correcta actualmente es cambiar a recyclerview ya que las vistas estan optimizadas, una misma vista se esta reciclando y cambiando su contenido, pero en tu código presentado en esta pregunta creo que picasso pudo solucionarlo, me llama la atención que comentas no se veian las imagenes. =0

Comment: Correcto Elena, no se visualizaban. Pero si, quizas mejor para el manejo de memoria el uso de un recyclerview. Gracias por tu ayuda, un saludo :)

Answer (score 0):

Para evitar el error `outOfMemory` cuando se debe visualizar bastantes imágenes, debes asegurar de que las que se han cargado, se eliminen de la memoria y usar un cache para no saturar el dispositivo de peticiones, te recomiendo usar la librería Glide.

En el PageAdapter puedes detectar cuando un elemento es retirado y liberizar el recurso.

```
    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        Log.i(TAG, "destroyItem: ");
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }
```

Si usas un `viewPage` como contenedor, se puede especificar los elementos que se mantengan en memoria o bien se precarguen con `setOffscreenPageLimit(número_paginas)`, si las fotos a mostrar son FullHD, 2K,4K,8K etc.. depende del dispositivo que vaya más fluido, si lo defines a 1:

```
                | pantalla disp |
pagina anterior | pagina actual | pagina siguiente
```

Pequeña desmotración de un visor de imágenes usando viewpager, glide y  zoom,rotate sobre el imageView [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/webserveis/41d1b7ef80eabbc27d4236047aa9f55b)