# Problemas al acceder a la galería Android Studio

Tags: java, android

estoy diseñando mi primera App para Android y me encuentro con el siguiente problema:

Cando accedo a mi galería presionando un botón, las imágenes que puedo utilizar son aquellas que provienen de los directorios "Download" y "Screenshot". El resto me da fallo.

Además, esto sólo funciona cuando accedo desde "Galería" y no "Fotos".
Mi versión de Android es la 4.3 (lo menciono por si tuviera alguna revelancia, puesto que el código en algunas partes necesita una superior)

Adjunto alguna imagen para dejarlo todo más claro:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En cuanto al código (es posible que sea algo caótico. Como ya dije, soy nuevo en esto):

```
import static android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA;
import static android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;


public class RegistroActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static String APP_DIRECTORY = "MyPictureApp/";
private static String MEDIA_DIRECTORY = APP_DIRECTORY + "PictureApp";

private final int MY_PERMISSIONS = 100;
private final int SELECT_PICTURE = 300;

private ImageView mSetImage;
private Button mOptionButton;
private RelativeLayout mRlView;

private String mPath;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_registro);
        Button bt_listo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_listo);
        bt_listo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()  {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                Toast toast1 =
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Registrado Correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast1.show();
                Intent intent_registrar = new Intent(RegistroActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent_registrar);
            }
        });

    mSetImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ibt_imagen);
    mOptionButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_galeria);

    mRlView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.id_registroactivity);

    if(mayRequestStoragePermission())
        mOptionButton.setEnabled(true);
    else
        mOptionButton.setEnabled(false);

    mOptionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Log.i("X: "+ mOptionButton.getX(), "Y: " + mOptionButton.getY());
            mOptionButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent.createChooser(intent, "Seleccionar imagen"), SELECT_PICTURE);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed(){

}

private boolean mayRequestStoragePermission() {

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        return true;

    if((checkSelfPermission(WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) &&
            (checkSelfPermission(CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED))
        return true;

    if((shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) || (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(CAMERA))){
        Snackbar.make(mRlView, "Permisos requeridos",
                Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction(android.R.string.ok, new View.OnClickListener() {
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, CAMERA}, MY_PERMISSIONS);
            }
        });
    }else{
        requestPermissions(new String[]{WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, CAMERA}, MY_PERMISSIONS);
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString("file_path", mPath);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    mPath = savedInstanceState.getString("file_path");
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        Uri path = data.getData();
        mSetImage.setImageURI(path);
        mSetImage.requestLayout();
        mSetImage.getLayoutParams().height = 140;
        mSetImage.getLayoutParams().width = 140;

        Toast.makeText(RegistroActivity.this, "Imagen cargada", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    if(requestCode == MY_PERMISSIONS){
        if(grantResults.length == 2 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            Toast.makeText(RegistroActivity.this, "Permisos aceptados", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mOptionButton.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }else{
        showExplanation();
    }
}

private void showExplanation() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegistroActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle("Permisos denegados");
    builder.setMessage("Permisos requeridos");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
            Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
            intent.setData(uri);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            finish();
        }
    });

    builder.show();
}
```

}

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/pt_alias"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:hint="@string/pt_alias"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/bt_listo"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/bt_listo"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/ibt_imagen"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/ibt_imagen" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/pt_correoElectronico"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pt_alias"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/pt_alias"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/pt_alias"
    android:hint="@string/pt_email"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/pt_alias"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/pt_alias" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/pt_contraseña"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pt_correoElectronico"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/pt_correoElectronico"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/pt_correoElectronico"
    android:hint="@string/pt_contraseña"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/pt_correoElectronico"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/pt_correoElectronico" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/pt_repetirContraseña"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pt_contraseña"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/pt_contraseña"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/pt_contraseña"
    android:hint="@string/pt_repetirPass"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/pt_contraseña"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/pt_contraseña" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/bt_listo"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pt_repetirContraseña"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/bt_listo"
    android:clickable="true"
    />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:id="@+id/logoRegistro"
    android:background="@drawable/logofinal"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ibt_imagen"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/pt_alias"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/bt_listo"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/bt_listo"
    android:gravity="right"
    />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/bt_galeria"
    android:background="@drawable/foto"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ibt_imagen"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/ibt_imagen"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/ibt_imagen" />
```

Y el error mostrado:

```
11-13 10:35:52.826 3137-3137/mario.rankit E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                        java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
                                                            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
                                                            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:623)
                                                            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
                                                            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:832)
                                                            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromStream(Drawable.java:783)
                                                            at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:673)
                                                            at android.widget.ImageView.setImageURI(ImageView.java:407)
                                                            at mario.rankit.RegistroActivity.onActivityResult(RegistroActivity.java:137)
                                                            at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5563)
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3496)
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3543)
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:159)
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Me preguntaba si alguno sabría como solucionarlo.
Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema relacionado a `OutOfMemoryError` es debido a que no se tiene la capacidad de alojar en memoria una o varias imagenes, te sugiero esta respuesta donde obtendras ideas para optimizar tus recursos:

El tema de la galerías creadas a partir de un widget `Gallery` siempre ha sido un problema, los problemas son básicamente relacionados a que las imágenes al cargarse dentro de la ejecución de `getView()`, son cargadas dentro del `ImageView` pero cuando el `ImageView` no esta visible estas no son liberadas del mismo, en realidad estas cargando las imágenes y manteniendolas aún sin ser visualizadas.

Una solución rápida es eliminar la imagen del ImageView cuando esta no es visualizada mediante [setBackgroundDrawable()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)) asignandole un valor null:

```
miImageView.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
```

Pero existen otras consideraciones importantes como es el peso de la imagen, en dispositivos pequeños en ocasiones no es necesario el cargado de una imagen de tamaño grande ya que su manipulación en memoria es difícil y más aún si tenemos varias instancias provocaremos  `OutofMemory`.

Te sugiero revisar estos tips de optimización:
**[Buena resolución imagen](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/6359/95)**

y en el caso de tu galería recomiendo uses **[Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)** o **[Glide](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en)** dentro de

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
 ...
 ...
```

para cargar las imágenes dentro del `ImageView`, no soy de recomendar librerías pero en este caso son 2 buenas opciones que recomiendo, en realidad optimizan la imagen que cargan dentro de los `ImageView`, esto resulta en un bajo consumo de memoria el cual evitara problemas relacionados a `OutofMemory`.

Comment: Gracias! Miraré a ver la respuesta en profundidad cuando vuelva a llegar a este punto. Por ahora lo dejé aparcado