# ¿Se puede colocar una imagen de gran tamaño como xxhdpi y ajustarla a las densidades menores, o hay que colocar una imagen para cada densidad?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-asynctask, android-drawerlayout

Tengo carpetas llenas de imágenes de distintas densidades. Quiero saber si es necesario colocar las 5 imágenes para las distintas densidades (hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi) o simplemente considerar sólo una imagen de gran tamaño, o sea, la xxxhdpi, y ajustarla dentro del layout y la pantalla del teléfono.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No entiendo los downvotes, es una pregunta básica pero importante.

Answer (score 5):

¿Se puede colocar una imagen de gran tamaño como xxhdpi y ajustarla a las densidades menores, o hay que colocar una imagen para cada densidad?

Puedes colocar una imagen de "gran tamaño" dentro de /drawable y no necesitarías agregar de otras densidades, pero debes tener cuidado porque podrías tener [problemas de consumo de memoria](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/6359/95), incluso puedes agregar una sola imagen de tamaño aceptable y esta se desplegaría sin problema en todas las densidades.

Pero definitivamente lo recomendable es agregar la imagen de acuerdo a su densidad para que se despliegue correctamente en todas las densidades:

```
36x36 (0.75x) : baja densidad.
48x48 (1.0x baseline) media densidad.
72x72 (1.5x) for alta densidad.
96x96 (2.0x) for extra alta densidad.
144x144 (3.0x) for extra-extra alta densidad.
192x192 (4.0x) for extra-extra-extra alta densidad.
```

---

Para nuevos desarrollos, puedes generar automáticamente las imágenes de iconos optimas a partir de una imagen de buena calidad,  ve a tu proyecto y selecciona `New` > `Image Asset`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Seleccionas `Asset Type` y escoges la imagen que deseas de buena resolución para generar todas las necesarias:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De esta forma se generarían automáticamente imágenes con las medidas necesarias en los directorio de cada densidad dentro de cada folder `/mipmap` :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Si es necesario tener las 5 resoluciones ya que **Android Studio** administra de forma "automática" dependiendo del tamaño de la pantalla que icono usar. Si no cumples con esto corres el riesgo de que tu icono se vea borroso.

**Nota**: Todas las imágenes las vamos a poner en la carpeta `drawable` y los iconos en la carpeta `mipmap`.

Comment: y que hay del tamaño de la apk , esta se eleva por las nubes por enésima de lo 50 MB en mi caso mi proyecto sin generar apk , pesa mas de 64 MB , que puedo hacer.

Comment: @GeanBConeAngulo Puedes usar un webservice y almacenar tus imagenes en un BD y mandiante un Asynctask cargar las imagenes asi evitas que tu apk sea demasiado pesada

Answer (score 1):

**Es necesario incluir imágenes distintas para cada densidad.**

El sitio oficial de Android para desarrolladores indica que para admitir varias densidades de pantalla hay que crear recursos en distintos tamaños, uno para cada densidad. *Fuente: [Cómo admitir varias densidades de pantalla](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html)*

Además, en [esta pregunta de Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37207443/how-to-put-single-image-for-different-screen-size) donde consultan por lo mismo, la respuesta aceptada indica precisamente lo que te digo aquí. También dan links para herramientas que permiten generar imágenes en distintos tamaños para admitir las diferentes densidades.

Comment: Que me dicees del tamaño de la apk o del proyecto entero , esta se eleva y se hace muy pesada , nose cual es el minimo peso recomendado , para un apk y si aporto mas recurso como imagenes que hace muy pesada , como puedo compensar esto , ayuda.

Comment: @GeanBConeAngulo La verdad no sé cuál sea la mejor solución a ese problema. Mejor que investigues un poco, y si no encuentras cómo, haz una nueva pregunta en este sitio.

Answer (score 1):

Más que decir si es necesario o no es necesario, yo voy a decir que es "evitable" generar imágenes para distintas densidades. Con una sola imagen y las medidas de la imagen parametrizadas en dimens.xml, en mi caso adapto un fichero dimens.xml para cada densidad (ésto me resulta necesario hacerlo en general, no sólo para las imágenes, así que lo aprovecho para este tema). El único detalle a tener en cuenta es que hay que usar una imagen que quede bien en todas las densidades, pero lo que queda bien para la densidad más amplia en pantalla, me suele quedar bien para las menores.

A mí ésta solución me vale siempre de momento porque no he tenido necesidad de usar grandes gráficos, así que para imágenes de botones, menús, etc. me resulta una opción bastante ágil.

Comment: y como ajustas el tamaño con dimens ?

Comment: para cada tamaño (densidad) de pantalla haz una carpeta con un fichero dimens.xml distinto, y en cada uno adaptas el tamaño de la imagen a dicho tamaño de pantalla. Así sólo tienes un fichero para la imagen pero la escalas para cada tamaño de pantalla.