# ViewPager de imágenes lento y pesado

Tags: android, optimización, manejo-de-memoria, android-viewpager, android-imageview

Buenas,

Tengo una actividad que muestra un `ViewPager` de imágenes.

```
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pagerHelp);
    HelpImageAdapter adapterView = new HelpImageAdapter(this);
    mPager.setAdapter(adapterView);
```

Uso un adaptador que extiende de `Pageradapter` para el `ViewPager`.

```
public class HelpImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter{

private Context mContext;
private int[] sliderImagesId = new int[]{
        R.drawable.help_images00, R.drawable.help_images01, R.drawable.help_images00,
        R.drawable.help_images01, R.drawable.help_images00, R.drawable.help_images01,
};

public HelpImageAdapter(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return sliderImagesId.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View v, Object obj) {
    return v == ((ImageView) obj);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int i) {
    ImageView mImageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    mImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    mImageView.setImageResource(sliderImagesId[i]);
    ((ViewPager) container).addView(mImageView, 0);
    return mImageView;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
}
}
```

Hasta aquí todo correcto, la actividad se ejecuta bien y puedo cambiar de imagen de un lado a otro.

El problema viene que la aplicación se ha vuelto muy lenta a la hora de añadir imágenes al parámetro sliderImagesId. Las imágenes pesan al rededor de `180kb` pero en el monitor de recursos mi aplicación usa `150MB y 200MB` de la memoria. Creo que el problema está aquí.

Me gustaría saber que puedo hacer para que el paso de imágenes sea más fluido y ocupe menos memoria RAM.

Muchas gracias de antemano, estoy aprendiendo mucho gracias a esta comunidad.

Comment: De seguro las imágenes que tienes poseen un gran tamaño o sino resolución haciendo que tu app funciona muy cargada. Podrías usar una librería que te ayude en el tema de imágenes tienes **Glide**, **Piccaso** o **Fresco**, yo siempre utilizo **Glide** me parece mas sencillo y eficaz.

Comment: @Natlum como curiosidad que peso tienen estos elementos,  R.drawable.help_images00, R.drawable.help_images01, R.drawable.help_images00,
        R.drawable.help_images01, R.drawable.help_images00, R.drawable.help_images01,

Comment: La resolución de las imágenes es de 600x800 y el peso es de 180kb

Comment: **Es muy raro que con un peso de 180kb te pueda provocar problemas, incluso son solo 6 imagenes**, a menos que sea un dispositivo de gama muy baja, te sugiero leer esta pregunta y las respuestas **http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6343/buena-resoluci%C3%B3n-de-una-imagen/6359#6359**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solucionado, gracias a @marlonpya.

He usado **Glide**, y ahora además de ir fluida la aplicación, también usa un 75% menos de memoria ram.

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int i) {
    ImageView mImageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    Glide
            .with(mContext)
            .load(sliderImagesId[i])
            .error(R.drawable.ic_help)
            .into(mImageView);
    return mImageView;
}
```

Para usar el Glide hay que incorporarlo en las dependencias.

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
```

Muchas gracias a todos por darme ese poquito de su tiempo.

Comment: jajaj **Glide** hace maravillas ; )