# Convertir imagen a base64 android

Tags: android, cámara, base64, realm

Mi código lo que hace es tomar de la galería una imagen y sacar su ruta en `string` y al aguardarlo en la base de datos aguarda la ruta de la imagen y la muestra.

Quiero poder tomar foto desde la cámara y también elegir desde la galería y  poder mostrar la imagen y que la imagen se convierta a `base64` y el resultado aguardarlo en la base de datos, para poder tener la posibilidad de al hacer servicios con web poder enviar un `string` que es el resultado de la imagen en `base64` si no me explique bien pueden comentarlo.

Mi codigo es el siguiente:
Activity:

```
public class CreateBits extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText editText;
    private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMG = 1;
    String imgDecodableString;
    Button nxtActivity;
    SharedPreferencesController spc;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_bits);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

        editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtTextNameBit);
        spc = new SharedPreferencesController(this);
    }
    public void addBit(View view){
        String bitName = editText.getText().toString();
        App.addBits(bitName, imgDecodableString, spc.getCategoryPID());
        finish();
    }
    public void Cancell(View view){
        finish();
    }
    public void addImage(View view){
        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        // Start the Intent
        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        try {
            // When an Image is picked
            if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                    && null != data) {
                // Get the Image from data
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                //Log.i("RegirstrarPerfil",data.toString());
                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                // Get the cursor
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                // Move to first row
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                imgDecodableString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();
                Log.i("Main", imgDecodableString);
                ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgCreateBit);
                // Set the Image in ImageView after decoding the String
                imgView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory
                        .decodeFile(imgDecodableString));
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked Image",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    }

}
```

Metodo de addBits:

```
public static Bits addBits(String bName, String bImage, long CID){
        long bitId;
        Log.i("App de Luis "," Bit guardado con CID "+CID);
        Number bitNumber = realm.where(Bits.class).max("bitId");
        if(bitNumber == null)
            bitId = 1;
        else
            bitId = (long)bitNumber + 1;
        realm.beginTransaction();
        Bits newBit = realm.createObject(Bits.class);
        newBit.setbitId(bitId);
        newBit.setbText(bName);
        newBit.setbImage(bImage);
        newBit.setCID(CID);
        realm.commitTransaction();
        return newBit;
    }
```

Comment: respondo a eso mismo en stackoverflow:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36189503/take-picture-and-convert-to-base64/36189666#36189666

Comment: si lo codifica a base64 y lo aguarda pero al momento de mostrarlo en la actividad no se visualiza la imagen, logre visualizarla al momento de seleccionarla pero cuando ya esta agregada ala base de datos y la muestro, no se visualiza, solo me trae el string.

Comment: ya quedo corregido... Gracias

Comment: @Exbaby estaba respondiendo a tu pregunta, en cuanto al consumo de memoria, te recomiendo revises esto : https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6343/viewpager-buena-resoluci%C3%B3n-de-una-imagen-outofmemoryerror/6359#6359

Comment: en que parte del código estas convirtiendo la foto tomada a base 64?

Comment: @ViktorRomero La respuesta esta colocada a bajo.

Answer (score 1):

Este es el código funcionando, para tomar foto de la cámara y de galería y convertirla a base64 para poder enviar a los servicios web mediante su string y a bitmap para mostrarla en la app. Espero les ayude.

Funcionando.

Variables:

```
private  int RESULT_LOAD_IMG = 0;
private int REQUEST_CAMERA = 0, SELECT_FILE = 1;
String imgDecodableString;
private String userChoosenTask;
```

Codigo  para elegir camara o galeria:

```
 public void addImage(View view){
    boolean result = CategoryUtility.checkPermission(CreateBits.this);

    //Ajustamos los elementos al DialogBox usando un AlertDialog...
    final CharSequence[] items = { "Tomar Foto", "Elegir Imagen", "Cancelar" };
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CreateBits.this);
    builder.setTitle("Agregar Foto!");
    builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            //Se revisa los permisos de la camara para android mas actuales si el andrpoid es menor a Marshmallow
            // checkPermission() devuelve true...
            boolean result = CategoryUtility.checkPermission(CreateBits.this);
            //Comprobamos la solicitud de la camara...
            if(items[item].equals("Tomar Foto")){
                //Almacené toma la foto en la variable de cadena userChoosenTask..
                userChoosenTask = "Tomar Foto";
                if(result)
                    cameraIntent();
                //Elegir desde la galeria
            }else if (items[item].equals("Elegir Imagen")){
                userChoosenTask = "Elegir Imagen";
                if(result)
                    galleryIntent();
            }else if(items[item].equals("Cancelar")){
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}
//Metodo de la camara
private void cameraIntent(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    //Nos da la captura de la camara
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);

}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults){
    switch (requestCode){
        case CategoryUtility.MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                if (userChoosenTask.equals("Tomar Foto"))
                    cameraIntent();
                else if (userChoosenTask.equals("Elegir Imagen"))
                    galleryIntent();
            }else {
                //denegar
            }
            break;
    }
}
private void galleryIntent(){
    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    // Start the Intent
    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
}
```

Codigo de procesamiento:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    try {
        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            final Uri imageUri = data.getData();
            final InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
            final Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
            imgDecodableString = encodeImage(selectedImage);
            ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgCreateBit);
            // Set the Image in ImageView after decoding the String
            imgView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory
                    .decodeFile(imgDecodableString));


            Uri selectedImages = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            // Get the cursor
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImages,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            // Move to first row
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            imgDecodableString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);

            imgDecodableString = encodeImages(imgDecodableString);
            cursor.close();
            Log.i("Main",imgDecodableString);

            imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgCreateBit);
            // Set the Image in ImageView after decoding the String

            Bitmap myBitmapAgain = decodeBase64(imgDecodableString);
            imgView.setImageBitmap(myBitmapAgain);


        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No haz escogido una imagen",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Algo salio mal", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
}
private String encodeImage(Bitmap bm) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,baos);
    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
    imgDecodableString = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);

    return imgDecodableString;
}

public static Bitmap decodeBase64(String input)
{
    byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.decode(input.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedBytes, 0, decodedBytes.length);
}
private String encodeImages(String path) {
    File imagefile = new File(path);
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    try{
        fis = new FileInputStream(imagefile);
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,baos);
    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
    imgDecodableString = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
    //Base64.de
    return imgDecodableString;

}
```

Comment: Me sale error con esta palabra CategoryUtility

Comment: @DanielPat El codigo estaba basado en categorias, por tal motivo en categorias podias hacer dichas funcionalidades.