# OutOfMemoryError usando base64 y realmdb al mostrar las imagenes en android

Tags: android, base64, realm

Mi código lo que hace es obtener una imagen desde la galería o de la cámara y convierte esta imagen a `base64`, después la aguarda en `RealmDB`, cuando la quiero mostrar la imagen, la convierto de `string` a `bitmap` y la muestro en un `cardview` con `recyclerview`, el detalle es que la `app` se hace lenta y después muestra el error  y posteriormente se detiene la aplicación.

También en el monitor de `android` veo que la memoria la consume demasiado.

Error:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 48771084 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 40MB until OOM
```

Codigo:

```
public class ImageDecode {

    static String imgDecodableString;

    public static String encodeImage(Bitmap bm) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new  ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100, baos);
        byte [] b=baos.toByteArray();
        try{
            System.gc();
            imgDecodableString= Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(OutOfMemoryError e){
            baos=new  ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,50, baos);
            b=baos.toByteArray();
            imgDecodableString=Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
            Log.e("EWN", "Out of memory error catched");
        }
        return imgDecodableString;
    }

    public static Bitmap decodeBase64(String input) {
        byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.decode(input.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedBytes, 0, decodedBytes.length);
    }

    public static String encodeImages(String path) {
        File imagefile = new File(path);
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try{
            fis = new FileInputStream(imagefile);
        }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,baos);
        byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
        try{
            System.gc();
            imgDecodableString = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
        }catch (OutOfMemoryError e){
            baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,50,baos);
            imgDecodableString = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
        }
        return imgDecodableString;

    }
}
```

Te esta forma muestro la imagen:

```
 holder.image.setImageBitmap(ImageDecode.decodeBase64(ProfList.get(position).getImage()));
```

Comment: tambien uso android:largeHeap="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false" y aun asi no funciona.

Comment: una forma también es recorrer todos los datos que deseas mostrar, extraer la imágenes volcarlas a un archivo en el directorio temporal y cargarlas de allí con glide usando su sistema de cache.

Answer (score 1):

Veo que usas

```
 System.gc();
```

algo importante a recordar sobre el `Garbage Collector` :

> "El GC es inteligente, de hecho, es más inteligente que tú y es
>   autónomo".

Así que si usas esto:

```
System.gc();
Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
```

para intentar llamar la ejecución del `Garbage Collector`, en realidad no es significativo.

Comentas que con 3 imagenes consumes cerca de 500MB lo cual es excesivo, te recomiendo revisar las imagenes y tratar de optimizarlas. Lo que realizas es correcto

```
  public static Bitmap decodeBase64(String input) {
        byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.decode(input.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedBytes, 0, decodedBytes.length);
    }
```

y debe funcionar sin problema a menos que las imágenes sean  de tamaño considerable. Te recomiendo usar [**GLIDE**](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) o **[PICASSO](http://square.github.io/picasso/)**, pero primeramente debes optimizar tus imagenes.

---

Te recomiendo esta pregunta y los tips de optimización:

[ViewPager, buena Resolución de una imagen "OutOfMemoryError"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6343/viewpager-buena-resoluci%C3%B3n-de-una-imagen-outofmemoryerror/6359#6359)

Esto es una buena pregunta, cual es la medida que deberían tener las imágenes en una aplicación para que la misma no consuma mucha memoria y por lo tanto sea lenta?.

En realidad la respuesta es que deben ser de una resolución aceptable pero un peso en kbs pequeño (algo similar a imágenes usadas en paginas web), esto para evitar principalmente dentro de la aplicación procesamiento y manipulación en memoria de la imagen y consumo de ancho de banda que pudiera ser innecesario.

Como lograr que tu imagen sea ligera?, bueno puedes trabajar con la **[compresión](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compresi%C3%B3n_de_imagen)** en bytes.

Aquí un tutorial: https://sites.google.com/site/ticvalcarcel/optimizacion-de-imagenes-para-internet/tamano-y-peso-de-las-imagenes

El SDK de Android tiene una forma de optimizar el cargado de imágenes, que implica el tomar un formato de imagen mas pequeno por medio de la clase **[BitmapFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeByteArray(byte[],%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options))**:

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Otras recomendadas considerando una previa optimización de las imágenes son el uso de dos librerías principalmente,

[**GLIDE**](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) y **[PICASSO](http://square.github.io/picasso/)**, cuya implementación es sencilla y muy similar.

Existen otras opciones pero realizando un benchmark a mi parecer son las mejores opciones.

En cuanto a tu problema :

> galería de imágenes que a medida que desplazo se me pone lenta la
>   aplicación.

Debes asegurar que la imagen sea desalojada del `ImageView` para que el `Garbage Collector` la pueda eliminar de memoria, esto en cuando ya no sea visible en la pantalla, porque si se están acumulando podrías tener después de cierto tiempo un  `Java.Lang.OutOfMemoryError`, lo puedes realizar con:

```
miImageView.setBackgroundDrawable(null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Detecta si la imagen ya está en memoria para obtenerla de allí.

```
if(imageView != null) {
    ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap().recycle();
}
imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
imageView.setImageResource(resID);
```

Mírate [como cargar imágenes grandes con eficiencia en Android dev](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html)

Otra manera de evitar posibles `out_of_memory` es usar alguna librería de carga de imágenes como es `glide`