# Como disminuir consumo de memoria en App Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, manejo-de-memoria

Hola amigos tengo una pregunta para ustedes. Tengo una app android la cual básicamente son dos actividades la `main_activity` y una detalles `activity`. La primera cuenta con un `recyclerView` con elementos y cuando toco uno entro a la actividad detalles el asunto es que cuando entro a la `activity_detalles` **el consumo de mi app se duplica y pasa de 65 mb a 125mb**, al salir de esta activity se mantiene ese consumo de memoria lo que hace que usuarios con teléfono de baja gama presenten fallas.

¿Como puedo liberar memoria al salir de la actividad detalles? para ello aquí le pongo mi actividad detalles.

```
    public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String EXTRA_POSITION = "position";
    RatingBar ratingBar;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

       // MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.llavedeapp));
        setSupportActionBar((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar));
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        // Set Collapsing Toolbar layout to the screen
        final CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar =
                (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
        // Set title of Detail page
        // collapsingToolbar.setTitle(getString(R.string.item_title));



        ratingBar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBarId);
        ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.calificado) + " " + ratingBar.getRating() + " " + getString(R.string.estrellas), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


        int postion = getIntent().getIntExtra(EXTRA_POSITION, 0);
        Resources resources = getResources();
        String[] places = resources.getStringArray(R.array.nombre_coctel);
        collapsingToolbar.setTitle(places[postion % places.length]);

        String[] placeDetails = resources.getStringArray(R.array.coctel_ingredientes);
        TextView placeDetail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.place_detail);
        placeDetail.setText(placeDetails[postion % placeDetails.length]);

        String[] placeLocations = resources.getStringArray(R.array.coctel_preparacion);
        TextView placeLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.place_location);
        placeLocation.setText(placeLocations[postion % placeLocations.length]);

        String[] acercaDelCoctel = resources.getStringArray(R.array.coctel_descripcion);
        TextView acercaCoctel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.acerca_del_coctel);
        acercaCoctel.setText(acercaDelCoctel[postion % acercaDelCoctel.length]);

        final TypedArray placePictures = resources.obtainTypedArray(R.array.places_picture);
        ImageView placePicutre = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        placePicutre.setImageDrawable(placePictures.getDrawable(postion % placePictures.length()));

        TextView textHistoriaCoctel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextHistoria);
        String[] historiaDelCoctel = resources.getStringArray(R.array.historia_coctel);
        TextView historiaCoctel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.historia_coctel);

        //Verifico que el cóctel tenga una historia en el el array de historia
        //de lo contrario desaparezco las vistas de la pantalla
        if ((historiaDelCoctel[postion]).isEmpty()) {
            textHistoriaCoctel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            historiaCoctel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            textHistoriaCoctel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            historiaCoctel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            historiaCoctel.setText(historiaDelCoctel[postion % historiaDelCoctel.length]);
        }
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "ca-app-pub-8600901870293215/4069468888");
                AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
                AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
                mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

                placePictures.recycle();


                ImageButton favoriteImageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.share_button);
                favoriteImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                        sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, conformarCuerpoEmail());
                        sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                        startActivity(sendIntent);
                    }
                });

                ImageButton shareImageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.email_button);
                shareImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        sendEmail();
                    }

                });
            }
        });


    }

    /* Se crea un hilo al llamar el método @sendEmail lo que hace que la app trabaje mejore el rendimiento en
       * telefonos de baja gama.*/
    public void sendEmail() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                composeEmail("xxxxx@correo.com", getString(R.string.comohacer), conformarCuerpoEmail());
            }
        }).start();
    }

    /*El método @conformarCuerpoEmail es el encargado de realizar el String correspondiente al cuerpo del mensaje
    * en el correo*/
    public String conformarCuerpoEmail() {

        int posicion = getIntent().getIntExtra(EXTRA_POSITION, 0);
        Resources resources = getResources();

        //Accediendo al nombre del  Cocktel
        String[] places = resources.getStringArray(R.array.nombre_coctel);
        String nombreTrago = places[posicion];

        //Accediendo al arreglo de Descripciones
        String[] place_desc = resources.getStringArray(R.array.coctel_descripcion);
        String descripcionTrago = place_desc[posicion];

        //Accediendo al arreglo de Ingredientes
        String[] placeDetails = resources.getStringArray(R.array.coctel_ingredientes);
        String ingredientesTrago = placeDetails[posicion];

        String[] placeLocations = resources.getStringArray(R.array.coctel_preparacion);
        String preparacionTrago = placeLocations[posicion];
        String cuerpoEmail;
        cuerpoEmail = "" + getString(R.string.nombre_trago) + "" + nombreTrago + "" + "\n"
                + getString(R.string.item_desc) + "\n" + " " + descripcionTrago + "\n"
                + " " + getString(R.string.ingredientes) + "\n" + " " + ingredientesTrago + "\n"
                + " " + getString(R.string.preparacion) + "\n" + " " + preparacionTrago;
        //Se devuelve el Cuerpo del mensaje que será enviado por correo
        return cuerpoEmail;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostResume() {
        super.onPostResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    /* El método @composeEmail es el que conforma el correo lanazando un Intent*/
    public void composeEmail(String addresses, String subject, String body) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:")); // only email apps should handle this
        intent.setType("text/html");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, addresses);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
        // Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getDataDirectory());
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Email"));
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Noto que usas un `ImageView`, generalmente el principal problema son imágenes, las cuales debemos eliminar su referencia o imágenes las cuales no están optimizadas y al cargarse en la aplicación provocan un alto consumo de memoria.

Te sugiero definir la variable del ImageView en la clase:

```
private ImageView placePicutre;
```

implementar el método `onDestroy()` donde asignarías un valor null al contenido del `ImageView`:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    placePicutreimgView.setImageDrawable(null);

}
```

Revisa nuevamente y comenta resultados.

---

Para detectar el problema te aconsejo leas **[Cómo explorar la memoria RAM usada](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/investigate-ram.html)**

Abre el `Android Monitor` ve a `Monitors`, navega tu aplicación y posteriormente descarga el archivo dando click al botón "Dump Java Heap".

> 1. En la parte superior del monitor Memory, haz clic en Dump Java Heap . Android Studio crea un archivo de resumen de montón con el nombre de
>      archivo application-id_yyyy.mm.dd_hh.mm.hprof, abre el archivo en
>      Android Studio y agrega el archivo a la lista Heap Snapshot de la
>      pestaña Captures.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> 2. En la pestaña Captures, haz clic con el botón secundario en el archivo y selecciona Export to standard .hprof.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Teniendo el archivo .hprof , puedes usar [**Memory Analizer**](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/downloads.php)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

para detectar leaks "sospechosos" de memoria:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

te aconsejo revisar esta pregunta:

[buena Resolución de una imagen causa "OutOfMemoryError"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6343/buena-resoluci%C3%B3n-de-una-imagen-causa-outofmemoryerror)

Comment: Brother es la mejor respuesta por mucho que me han dado en esta plataforma e incluso que haya visto yo que se haya dado aquí. GRACIAS!!

Comment: Pero me acabo de dar cuenta de una cosa la app se sobre carga cuando voy a la actividad anterior dando click en el icono de la flecha que da atras en el Toolbar de la activity detalles o sea esa misma que tengo ahí.

Comment: mira aqui te pongo un video fijate que aumenta el consumo en el caso que te digo o sea ir de detail a Main activity pero cuando voy por la flecha del toolbar   http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aHtWLgI2EMA

Comment: Al dar click, regresas a DetailActivity?

Comment: mira aqui te pongo un video fijate que aumenta el consumo en el caso que te digo o sea ir de detail a Main activity pero cuando voy por la flecha del toolbar youtube.com/watch?v=aHtWLgI2EMA