# Error al usar la función BitmapFactory.decodeFile

Tags: java, android, bitmap, out-of-memory-error

Tengo este código:

```
if(imgFile.exists()) {
    BitmapFactory.Options btOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    btOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    btOptions.inSampleSize = 8;

    Log.e("IMAGEN ERROR", imgFile.getAbsolutePath());

    //Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
    //final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    //options.inSampleSize = 8;

    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
    if (myBitmap != null) {
        int imgHeight = myBitmap.getHeight();
        int imgWidth = myBitmap.getWidth();
        ImageView myImage = holder.image;
        myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
    }
}
```

Me da este error:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 552960012 byte
>   allocation with 4193416 free bytes and 418MB until OOM

El error me lo da aqui:

```
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

Creo que la imagen pesa alrededor de **18mb**

Comment: Android me parce que el limite de cargar una imagen en memoria es de 2048x2048, yo recurro a la libreria BigImageView https://github.com/Piasy/BigImageViewer

Comment: Esa solución es perfecta, la unica pega es que no puedo modificar el layout para poner el propio de la libreria. Pero muchas gracias @Webserveis si lo pones como respuesta tendras mucha puntuación

Comment: @SamsungDeveloper te daré mi sugerencia, o usas imágenes optimizadas o usa picasso o glide. ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Añadir un manejo de excepciones para catch [OutOfMemoryError](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html) en ocasiones puede no ser suficiente, **probablemente no será capaz de atrapar este error, e incluso puede no saberse de donde se origino en realidad este error.**
- usar `android:largeHeap="true"` dentro de tu AndroidManifest.xml puede no ser suficiente.

Las dos recomendaciones anteriores pueden funcionar (aunque probablemente no en todos los dispositivos), en realidad no están solucionando el problema,

---

Como una "solución", puedes usar un sampleo de la imagen original mediante la propiedad [inSampleSize](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html) de [BitmapFactory.Options()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html)

> [inSampleSize](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html) Si se establece en un valor> 1, solicita al
>   decodificador que submuestre la imagen original, devolviendo una
>   imagen más pequeña para ahorrar memoria.

```
 BitmapFactory.Options btOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
 btOptions.inSampleSize = 4;
 Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath(), btOptions);
```

Sin embargo esto tiene como inconveniente que tus imagenes se muestren borrosas o pixeladas.

Otra opción que es recomendable es usar [**GLIDE**](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) y **[PICASSO](http://square.github.io/picasso/)**, cuya implementación es sencilla y tiene muy buena administración de la memoria para imágenes.

**te recomiendo principalmente optimizar tus imágenes para que sean adecuadas para tu dispositivo.**

Revisa esta pregunta:

**[buena Resolución de una imagen causa "OutOfMemoryError"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6343/buena-resoluci%C3%B3n-de-una-imagen-causa-outofmemoryerror/6359#6359)**

Answer (score 3):

Prueba con agregar al `manifest.xml` que el heap de memoria sea más grande.

```
<application
    ...
    android:largeHeap="true">
```

En la documentación oficial explican [como cargar eficientemente imágenes grandes](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html)

Si es para visualizar una imagen "gigante" puedes usar:

- [subsampling scale image view](https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view)
- [BigImageViewer](https://github.com/Piasy/BigImageViewer) esta librería usa la de subsampling scale image view, pero le añade la función de carga de imágenes con Glide, Picaso etc...

Si se usa dentro de un `viewPager` para crear una galería, se puede cargar una imagen de previsualización, mientras se está cargando la grande en memoria.

Comment: Ya lo tenia puesto y aun asi me daba error

Answer (score 1):

Al final lo he conseguido haciendo unas modificaciones en el código:

```
if(imgFile.exists()) {
    BitmapFactory.Options btOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    btOptions.inSampleSize = 8;

    try {
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath(), btOptions);

        if (myBitmap != null) {
            int imgHeight = myBitmap.getHeight();
            int imgWidth = myBitmap.getWidth();
            ImageView myImage = holder.image;
            myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

            Double imgNewHeight = Metodos.calcularHeightImagen(screenWidth, screenHeight, imgWidth, imgHeight);
            holder.image.getLayoutParams().height = imgNewHeight.intValue();
            holder.image.getLayoutParams().width = screenWidth.intValue();
        }
    }
    catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

He añadido el `try-catch` y añadido la variable `btOptions` en la función `decodeFile`

Comment: Agregar manejo de excepciones para OutOfMemoryError no puede ser una solución, funcionaría en tu dispositivo pero en otros tal vez no. samplear la imagen original puede ayudar, pero tendrás una imagen borrosa o no de buena calidad.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a cambiar en el manifest file lo siguient:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false" , 
android:largeHeap="true"
```

tal y como indican [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32244851/androidjava-lang-outofmemoryerror-failed-to-allocate-a-23970828-byte-allocatio)

Comment: No es aconsegable desactivar el hardwareAcelerated, porque después toda la app va un poco lenta, en los recyclerview se nota mucho.