# ¿Dónde y cómo colocar ImageView.setImageDrawable(null)? para eliminar de la memoria

Tags: android, android-studio, imagen, android-imageview, android-drawerlayout

Tengo el siguiente **código**:

```
if (contarImg == 1) {
            imagen.setImageResource(R.drawable.imagen01);
}
if (contarImg == 2) {
            imagen.setImageResource(R.drawable.imagen02);
}
if (contarImg == 3) {
            imagen.setImageResource(R.drawable.imagen03);
}
if (contarImg == 4) {
            imagen.setImageResource(R.drawable.imagen04);
}
```

Y así continuo colocando muchas imágenes.
El problema es que necesito que se borre de la memoria las imágenes que ya no los utilizo.

Sé que debo escribir: `ImageView.setImageDrawable(null)` pero no se dónde y cómo para que no se me cierre la aplicación con tantas imágenes.

Si existe otra forma también se los agradezco.

Comment: Define a grandes rasgos que realiza tu aplicación para dar más opiniones.

Comment: Voy poniendo las imágenes que son preguntas y luego tiene las alternativas para responderlas en un radioGroup. Son como 40 imágenes.

Comment: Ok Hipolito, entonces son varias imágenes en varios ImageView, no únicamente el que se llama "imagen"? Si esto es así indica que tamaño tiene en bytes la más grande y la más pequeña :)

Comment: 11KB y 67KB la más grande

Comment: =0 mmm no creo que sea considerable, cuantas imágenes agregas como máximo?

Comment: como 100 imágenes

Answer (score 0):

Si usas el mismo `ImageView` que es `imagen`, y estas usando el método `setImageResource()`  simplemente realiza esto:

```
imagen.setImageResource(0);
```

con esto eliminas la referencia del recurso cargado. Lo puedes realizar cuando finalizas la Activity.

---

> Sé que debo escribir: ImageView.setImageDrawable(null) pero no se
>   dónde y cómo para que no se me cierre la aplicación con tantas
>   imágenes.

Es importante que antes que nada optimices tus imagenes, revisa los tips comentados en esta respuesta:

[buena Resolución de una imagen causa "OutOfMemoryError"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6343/buena-resoluci%C3%B3n-de-una-imagen-causa-outofmemoryerror)

Comment: Gracias jorgesys. Si revicé: [https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6343/buena-resoluci%C3%B3n-de-una-imagen-causa-outofmemoryerror].  No puedo poner al final de la actividad, porque no me deja llegar allí, se cierra antes de llegar al final.

Comment: Entonces debo poner la imagen 01, luego la imagen 02 y debe eliminarse la imagen 01 y así sucesivamente.