# OutOfMemoryError Al Cargar Imagenes Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, imagen, android-imageview, bitmap

Tengo un problema con la carga de imagenes al seleccionarlas desde el dispositivo, esto en android studio, mi código para abrir las imagenes es el siguiente:

```
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(new Intent().
                                    setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT).
                                    setType("image/*"), "Selecciona una imagen"),
                            Constants.COD_SELECT_IMAGE);
```

En mi onActivityResult lo tengo de la siguiente manera:

```
if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                Uri imageUri = data.getData();
                if (imageUri != null){
                    Image.setImageURI(null);
                    Image.setImageURI(imageUri);
                }
                try {
                    ImageBitmap = null;
                    ImageBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), imageUri);
                    Image.setImageBitmap(null);
                    byte[] byteArray = ImageManager.compressImage(ImageBitmap, 50);
                    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray,0, byteArray.length);
                    Glide.with(this)
                            .load(bmp)
                            .centerCrop()
                            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                            .skipMemoryCache(true)
                            .thumbnail(0.1f)
                            .into(Image);
                }catch (IOException iEx){
                    Log.d(Constants.SET_BITMAP_IMAGE, " >> Error to send 'ImageBitmap'");
                    iEx.printStackTrace();
                    setErrorImage();
                }
            }
```

El error me dice que es exactamente en esta linea:

```
ImageBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), imageUri);
```

Esta imagen decidi cargarla con Glide para que evitara este error pero aun asi sigue saliendome, de ante mano muchas gracias.

**========================= Actualización =========================**

Este es mi StackTrace:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 38340876 byte allocation with 4792728 free bytes and 4MB until OOM
    at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStreamInternal(BitmapFactory.java:882)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:858)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:896)
    at android.provider.MediaStore$Images$Media.getBitmap(MediaStore.java:897)
    at com.smb.smbrv24.Views.Avtivitys.RegisterFree.onActivityResult(RegisterFree.java:581)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7165)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4994)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5041)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:229)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1875)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: Puedes adjuntar el starcktrace del error?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Para otra persona que presente este mismo error solucione mi problema de la siguiente manera:

```
                Uri imageUri = data.getData();

                InputStream imageStream = null;
                try {
                    imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
                }catch (FileNotFoundException fEx){
                    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: error to open file for ''imageUri''");
                    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: >>>> " + fEx.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Error al Cargar la Imagen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                try {
                    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                    byte[] byteArray = ImageManager.compressImage(bmp, 50);
                    Glide.with(this)
                            .load(byteArray)
                            .centerCrop()
                            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.AUTOMATIC)
                            .skipMemoryCache(false)
                            .thumbnail(0.1f)
                            .into(Image);
                }catch (Exception eX){
                    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: error to compress image");
                    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: >>>> " + eX.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Error al Comprimir Imagen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

En mi metodo *ImageManager.compressImage* lo tengo de esta manera:

```
public static byte[] compressImage(Bitmap bitmap, int quality){
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, stream);
    return stream.toByteArray();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Primeramente al usar `Glide` es recomendable uses el cache para evitar volver a descargar la imagen,

por lo tanto debes usar

```
.skipMemoryCache(false)
```

en lugar de  `.skipMemoryCache(true)` o no definir esta propiedad.

también debes usar

```
.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.AUTOMATIC)
```

en lugar de `.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)` Para que automaticamente se selecciones una estrategia de almacenamiento de cache basada en los recursos.

```
 Glide.with(this)
                            .load(bmp)
                            .centerCrop()
                            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.AUTOMATIC)
                            .skipMemoryCache(false)
                            .thumbnail(0.1f)
                            .into(Image);
```

Pero lo mas importante es optimizar tus imagenes para evitar descargar imagenes demasiado grandes innecesariamente para un dispositivo movil, revisa

[Buena resolución de imagen causa "OutOfMemoryError"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6343/buena-resoluci%c3%b3n-de-imagen-causa-outofmemoryerror)