# ¿Por que mi app se cierra cuando agrego un editText?

Tags: android-studio

estoy haciendo una app que cambie de imagen(imageview) cada vez que el usuario cierre la aplicación y la vuelva abrir,

[image: este es la app]

como pueden ver ese mango es el imageview y funciona, cambia su imagen cuando la app se cierra y se vuelve abrir.pero cuando agrego un editText en la parte de abajo de la imagen, la app se abre de vez en cuando a veces ni abre. 
reviso la ventana que dice RUN y me sale este error.

```
A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 4040 (le.fruttyappdos)
```

y se cierra la app. nota(estoy seguro que no es el código de la parte lógica porque cuando no agrego el edidText funciona perfectamente)

aquí lo que encontré en LogCat

```
04-01 19:46:13.016 4354-4354/com.example.fruttyappdos E/dalvikvm-heap: Out of memory on a 16000012-byte allocation.
```

Comment: Hola mauricio, importante buscar en el LogCat donde indique "Caused by" ahí se encuentra la descripción especifica del error, buscala y agregala a tu pregunta, saludos.

Comment: amigo discúlpame ,pero en el LogCat no encontré ningún "Caused by" solo lo que acabe de agregar y la linea anterior

Comment: Hola @mauricio mira puedes revisar como usar de una manera adecuada el LogCat, si tu app se cierra seguramente se muestra info ahí. Con respecto a la actualización veo que el problema es "Out of memory" , te sugiero agregar como cargas la imagen y revisa que medida tienen las imagenes, revisa esta respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6343/buena-resoluci%c3%b3n-de-imagen-causa-outofmemoryerror/6359#6359