# ¿Como solucionar el error visual studio 2019 java.lang.outofmemoryerror? Xamarin Form

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2019

Tengo un proyecto en xamarin form y al ejecutarlo con el emulador me sale el error java.lang.outofmemoryerror. Busque y una de las soluciones es que aumente el JavaMaxHeapSize en Android> Propiedades > Opciones de Android > Avanzado > Tamaño máximo de almacenamiento Java, lo aumente a 1G que es lo que todos recomiendan pero me sigue saliendo el mismo error. ¿Que puedo hacer?

Comment: intenta subiendole un poco más de tamaño para probar.... intenta con unos 2, 3, o 4 gb

Comment: Ya lo intente y me sale B: invalid opcode ba - invokedynamic requires --min-sdk-version >= 26

Comment: No debe ser necesario modificar alguna propiedad en la IDE, primero agrega información de lo que realiza tu proyecto (revisar [ask]), es importante revisar que realiza y porque provoca outofmemoryerror, revisa : https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6343/buena-resoluci%c3%b3n-de-imagen-causa-outofmemoryerror