# Aplicación Android/Java: actividad tarda en cargar en dispositivo antiguo con 1GB de RAM

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ram

Estoy programando una aplicación en Android/Java. La aplicación carga una base de datos preelaborada almacenada en assets. Son 180 minerales con 29 campos de texto. Un ejemplo de entrada sería:

```
INSERT INTO MINE180 VALUES('1','oro','oro','oro','#a2ceef','No silicatos','Elementos nativos','Au','Cúbico.','Hidrotermal','Asociado a venas de cuarzo.','Sedimentario','Placeres.','Magmático','Yacimientos IOCG.','no','','no','','Cristales octaédricos. Arborescente, escamoso, en pepitas.','Amarillo característico.','Opaco.','Metálico.','Amarilla característica.','19.3','2.5-3','---','Astillosa, dentada.','(1)The Arkenstone. iRocks.com.','http://www.irocks.com/minerals/specimen/46020');
```

Estoy probando la aplicación en modo debug con una tablet que tiene Android 4.4.4 y 1GB de RAM, y, al entrar en una actividad, se queda congelada unos segundos antes de entrar. Se queda parada mucho más tiempo la primera vez que lanza la actividad que las sucesivas.

Al cargar los 180 minerales en un listview con nombre, grupo e imagen no da error la tablet de 1GB y carga rápido. La actividad que da error es un quiz que genera 15 tipos de preguntas tipo "¿Cuál de los siguientes minerales pertenece al grupo de los sulfuros y sulfosales?" consultando los campos y añadiendo los cuatro minerales de opciones al azar con números random de rango (1,180).

Recibo la advertencia en la pestaña debug de Android Studio:

```
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3512K, 47% free 4383K/8176K, paused 20ms, total 20ms
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 766K, 50% free 4152K/8176K, paused 13ms, total 16ms
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 403K, 48% free 4260K/8176K, paused 13ms, total 17ms
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 418K, 47% free 4350K/8176K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 432K, 46% free 4442K/8176K, paused 13ms, total 13ms
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 417K, 44% free 4579K/8176K, paused 13ms, total 14ms
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 502K, 43% free 4677K/8176K, paused 13ms, total 13ms
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 513K, 42% free 4797K/8176K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 532K, 40% free 4938K/8176K, paused 14ms, total 18ms
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 586K, 38% free 5071K/8176K, paused 14ms, total 15ms
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 622K, 37% free 5213K/8176K, paused 16ms, total 17ms
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 652K, 35% free 5372K/8176K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 691K, 33% free 5545K/8176K, paused 21ms, total 21ms
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 747K, 31% free 5720K/8176K, paused 18ms, total 23ms
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 801K, 28% free 5900K/8176K, paused 18ms, total 18ms
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 250K, 28% free 5933K/8176K, paused 17ms, total 17ms
I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 6.569MB for 2940-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 28% free 5936K/8180K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 6.572MB for 2940-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 14K, 28% free 5931K/8184K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 6.567MB for 2940-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4K, 28% free 5938K/8188K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 6.574MB for 2940-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 28% free 5941K/8192K, paused 17ms, total 17ms
I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 6.576MB for 2940-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 67K, 28% free 5952K/8196K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 6.587MB for 2940-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4K, 28% free 5961K/8200K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 6.597MB for 4016-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 28% free 5965K/8204K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 6.601MB for 4016-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 129K, 28% free 5978K/8208K, paused 16ms, total 17ms
I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 6.612MB for 2940-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 28% free 5980K/8212K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 6.615MB for 2940-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 8K, 28% free 5982K/8216K, paused 16ms, total 17ms
I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 6.618MB for 4016-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 28% free 5986K/8220K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 6.622MB for 4016-byte allocation
```

Este problema no ocurre en un modelo con Android 5.1.1 y 2GB de RAM.

La clase Java de la actividad que genera el problema tiene 2600 líneas, por lo que no la puedo compartir más que con el [siguiente enlace](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b75kMMGCQG2BDt61MQI7MUSsRqqUamP1/view?usp=sharing). El layout xml es el siguiente:.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="com.geologyapplications.minerals.Ficha"
    android:theme="@android:style/Holo.Light.ButtonBar"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbarTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|end"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="#ffff00"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.WindowTitle"
            android:visibility="visible"/>
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/txtPregunta"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/resps">
            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:id="@+id/a"
                android:textSize="16sp"/>
            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:id="@+id/b"
                android:textSize="16sp"/>
            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:id="@+id/c"
                android:textSize="16sp"/>
            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:id="@+id/d"
                android:textSize="16sp"/>
            </RadioGroup>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/ok"
                        android:id="@+id/a1"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/correcta"/>
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/falso"
                        android:id="@+id/a2"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/incorrecta"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/ok"
                        android:id="@+id/b1"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/correcta"/>
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/falso"
                        android:id="@+id/b2"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/incorrecta"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/ok"
                        android:id="@+id/c1"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/correcta"/>
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/falso"
                        android:id="@+id/c2"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/incorrecta"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/ok"
                        android:id="@+id/d1"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/correcta"/>
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/falso"
                        android:id="@+id/d2"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/incorrecta"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:text="@string/responder"
                android:id="@+id/responder"
                android:textSize="16sp"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:text="@string/siguiente"
                android:id="@+id/siguiente"
                android:textSize="16sp"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:text="@string/finalizar"
                android:id="@+id/finalizar"
                android:textSize="16sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:minHeight="40dp">
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Mi pregunta es si podría mejorar el código para que el dispositivo con 1GB de RAM no se quede congelado, o simplemente el programa efectúa muchos cálculos y sería conveniente que pusiera en el graddle de mínima versión SDK la API 5.1 (presumiblemente dispositivos con más de 1GB de RAM) y añadir como requisito mínimo 2GB de RAM en las especificaciones del store.

Comment: El problema es que estás manejando todo en el main thread, lo que te recomiendo es manejar las llamadas a base de datos en un hilo a parte y retornar la respuesta. También recomiendo que uses un patrón de arquitectura para que puedas ordenar mejor tu código

Comment: En que consiste la aplicación que carga y como lo carga?

Comment: @Jorgesys Compartiría el código completo, pero lo siento, la aplicación es previsible que alcance 10k usuarios y me dé algo de dinero con los anuncios remunerados y la versión de pago (tiene un sistema de monedas, les doy 300 por ver un anuncio y les quito una por ver una ficha y dos por cada pregunta), y al verlo en mi perfil (donde voy a poner un link) podrían copiarme el código (o mejorarlo) y la base de datos y publicarla más barata.

Comment: @josé miguel zea guerrero Aprendí a programar tras la Universidad haciendo cursos en Udemy y Youtube y aunque se me dan bien la programación y las matemáticas, no entiendo muy bien cómo elaborar un patrón de arquitectura. Imagino que debo hacer una clase generaPregunta que sustituya a los métodos y reciba como parámetro el tipo de pregunta (??). No se me ocurre nada más. Gracias, lo de los hilos creo que lo conseguiré buscando algo de información. Ya os diré si haciendo hilos carga en la tablet de 1GB de RAM.

Comment: @josé miguel zea guerrero Los consejos son muy útiles y es importante para mí. Si amplías un poco más los consejos en una respuesta te doy 50 puntos de recompensa. ¡Gracias!

Comment: Una pregunta @Universal_learner la aplicación carga las imágenes que obtiene de la base de datos?, recuerda agregar más información a tu pregunta como la que escribes en los comentarios.

Comment: @Jorgesys No, las imágenes las guardo en la carpeta drawable. Ok, actualizo la pregunta y borro los comentarios.

Comment: Hola @Universal_learner me parece que son dos detalles, te sugiero revisar mi respuesta, puedes iniciar llamando los métodos que realizan consulta a la base de datos usando un AsyncTask y te aseguro notarás cambios, saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al ver el mensaje en el LogCat y de acuerdo a lo que comentas me parece que son dos puntos a corregir, el consumo de memoria y evitar bloqueos en la UI.

---

**1 )** Primeramente revisar tu código hay dos puntos que pueden afectar el rendimiento de tu aplicación, primeramente noto que en tu aplicación tienes varios `ImageView` :

```
private ImageView a1, a2, b1, b2, c1, c2, d1, d2;
```

los cuales haces visibles o invisibles:

```
a1 = findViewById(R.id.a1);
a1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
a2 = findViewById(R.id.a2);
a2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
b1 = findViewById(R.id.b1);
b1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
b2 = findViewById(R.id.b2);
b2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
c1 = findViewById(R.id.c1);
c1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
c2 = findViewById(R.id.c2);
c2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
d1 = findViewById(R.id.d1);
d1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
d2 = findViewById(R.id.d2);
d2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

pero estos están cargando imágenes de `/drawable` directamente en el layout.

**Lo que debes realizar es optimizar las imágenes ya que en ocasiones son de tamaño considerable y el manejo en memoria puede causar que se ralentice tu aplicación en incluso consuma un porcentaje importante de memoria de tu dispositivo móvil**, este enlace te sugiere varias opciones para optimizar las imágenes en tu aplicación.

[**¿Como evitar Out of memory en aplicación y optimizar imágenes Android?**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6343/buena-resoluci%C3%B3n-de-imagen-causa-outofmemoryerror/6359#6359)

---

**2 )** El segundo punto es que realizas consultas a la base de datos,

```
  public void updateCoins() {
        int coins = 0;
        Cursor cursor = null;
        SQLiteDatabase db = null;
        try {
            db = openOrCreateDatabase(databaseStorageName, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
            cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT Coins FROM COINS", null);
            ...
            ...
            ... 

public void updateCoins2() {
        int coins = 0;
        Cursor cursor = null;
        SQLiteDatabase db = null;
        try {
            db = openOrCreateDatabase(databaseStorageName, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
            cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT Coins FROM COINS", null);
            ...
            ...
            ...
```

pero este último método lo estas llamando cada vez que muestras la aplicación o que regresa de segundo plano:

```
   @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        updateCoins2();
    }
```

Esto puede ocasionar que tu aplicación se ralentice y se bloquee, **para evitar bloqueos en la interfaz de usuario puedes usar `AsyncTask` o `Corroutinas`**, si usas Java puedes usar un `AsyncTask`, como ejemplo puedse llamas el método `updateCoins2()` de esta forma :

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground( Void... voids ) {
        updateCoins2(); //Llama método.
        return null;
    }
}.execute();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de revisar mi código. Haré caso de las sugerencias. Te comento si mejora el rendimiento cuando haya hecho los cambios.

Comment: Claro que si, me comentas los resultados, pero con estos cambios deben ayudar mucho a dispositivos de gama baja o con capacidades de memoria pequeñas, saludos.

Comment: Mañana por la mañana lo cambio. Sospecho que son las fotos, porque cada vez que hace una pregunta hace un updateCoins y ahí no va lento. Las voy a poner con fondo transparente y más pequeñas, adaptadas a cada dispositivo, son solo el tick verde y la cruz roja de acertada o fallada.

Comment: Las imagenes no tienes que cambiarlas de tamaño pero si de peso (bytes), puedes optimizarlas y eso ayudara a consumir menos memoria y tu aplicaciòn funcionarà mucho mejor.

Comment: Funciona más rápido, muchas gracias.